# Group without join in mysql

Tags: mysql, join, group-by, mysql-workbench

I have a database with many individuals. Each individual has observations for many quarte

```
`
+----+---------+--------+--------+
| az | quarter | imp    |year
+----+---------+--------+--------+
|  1 | 1.2012  |      6 |  2012  |
|  1 | 2.2012  |      5 |  2012  |
|  1 | 3.2012  |      5 |  2012  |
|  1 | 4.2012  |      5 |  2012  |
|  2 | 1.2012  |      3 |  2012  |
|  2 | 2.2012  |      3 |  2012  |
|  2 | 3.2012  |      4 |  2012  |
|  2 | 4.2012  |      3 |  2012  |
|....|  ....   |        |
+----+---------+--------+-------+
`
```

I need to create a column that has for each year the sum of the quarters

```
+----+---------+--------+--------+
| az | year    | imp    |imp.year
+----+---------+--------+--------+
|  1 |   2012  |      6 |  21    
|  1 |   2012  |      5 |  21
|  1 |   2012  |      5 |  21
|  1 |   2012  |      5 |  21
|  2 |   2012  |      3 |  13
|  2 |   2012  |      3 |  13
|  2 |   2012  |      4 |  13
|  2 |   2012  |      3 |  13
|....|  ....   |        |
+----+---------+--------+-------+
```

I used

```
CREATE TABLE IMP_TOT_YEAR AS SELECT
az, year, SUM(imp) as imp.year,
FROM IMP_TOT
GROUP BY az,year;
```

then

```
CREATE TABLE complete AS SELECT
a.*, b.imp.year,
FROM IMP_TOT as a
left join IMP_TOT_YEAR as b 
on a.az=b.az and a.anno=b.year ;
```

I have more than 10 variables like imp and many years so the join is too slow.
It's running from more than 2 hours.
I was looking for a method without join like:

```
if quarter=1.2012 then imp.year = imp in (actual_row+1)+imp in (actual_row+2)+imp in (actual_row+3)

else imp.year = imp.year in (actual_row -1)
```

So I don't need to esecute subquery or join. Is it possible?

Comment: Why do you repeat the year in the quarter column?

Comment: How large is your table?

Comment: What indexes do you have on your table? If you have an index on `(az, year)` the `GROUP BY` should be fast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `join` should be fine if you add indexes to `IMP_TOT_YEAR`:

```
create index IMP_TOT_YEAR_az_yr on IMP_TOT_YEAR(az, yr);
```

It sounds like you have a lot of data, so using an intermediate table might be fast.

On the other hand, if you want to do it in one table, be sure you have an index on `IMP_TOT(az, yr)` and try:

```
SELECT t.*,
       (SELECT SUM(imp) as imp.year,
        FROM IMP_TOT t2
        WHERE t2.az = t.az and t2.yr = t.yr
       ) as YearTot
FROM IMP_TOT;
```

Comment: I did : `create index IMP_TOT_YEAR_az_yr on IMP_TOT_year(az, year);
create index IMP_TOT_az_Tr on IMP_TOT(az, quarter);` in 30 sec. finished!!!! I'm new in mysql and didn't know that creating indixes make query so fast. I need to do that every time a create a new table?

Comment: @user3384159 . . . MySQL has pretty good documentation on indexes.  You can start here:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/optimization-indexes.html.

Comment: Now that I did
`create index IMP_TOT_YEAR_az_yr on IMP_TOT_year(az, year);`
is faster, but if i did  also
`create index IMP_TOT_az_yr on IMP_TOT(az, year);`
is it even faster?

Comment: @user3384159 . . . The two indexes should be pretty similar for this query.  Adding `imp` to either as a third column should provide a bit of an additional boost.